# Let $\langle a_n\rangle$ be a sequence where $a_n = {\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^j2/n}$ then

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $\langle a_n\rangle$ be a sequence where $a_n = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^j2/n$
>
> 1. is oscillatory
> 2. diverges to $+\infty$
> 3. diverges to $-\infty$
> 4. converges to $0$

I think by taking subsequences $\langle a_{2n}\rangle =(2/n) +(2/n) +\ldots +(2/n)$ ($n$-times) ${}= 2$ and $\langle a_{2n-1}\rangle = -2/n -2/n -\ldots -2/n$ ($n$-times) ${}=-2$ which is cunverging to $2$ and $-2$ respectively. So that the sequence is oscillatory. I have doubt taking this type of subsequence is right or wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is 4). Write down the sums $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k}$ and convince yourself that these are bounded. So if you multiply these by $\frac 2n $ and let $n \to \infty$ you get $0$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $a_n=\frac{2}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^j=\frac{1}{n} \cdot (1-(-1)^{n+1})$ and

$|a_n| \le 2/n.$ for all $n$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: this means $-2/n{\leq }a_n{\leq}2/n$ then by sandwitch theorem $<a_n> converges to 0

Answer (score 0):

1)$a_n= (-2/n)$, $n$ is odd.

2) $a_n=0$, $n$ is even.

1')$\lim_{ k \rightarrow \infty } a_{2k+1} =0$, $k=0,1,2,..;$

2')$ \lim_{l \rightarrow \infty} a_{2l}=0, l=1,2,3,...;$

Lemma:

The $2$ subsequences $a_{2l}, a_{2k+1}$,

$l=1,2,..,$  $k=0,1,2,..,$

converge to $0$, hence $a_{n}$ converges to $0$.

Can you prove the Lemma?

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n {= {\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^j2/n}\\\to a_{2k}=0\\,\\a_{2k+1}=-{2\over 2k+1}}$$then this sequence **oscillatorily converges to 0**.